# Subarray datatype with mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi4py

I'm making a simple program where i'm trying to send 4 x 4 matrix sub-matrices from a 8x8 matrix using mpi4py. My approach is to use the subarray datatype, but i keep getting segmentation faults.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

sizes = (8,8)    # Matrix dimensions
subsizes = (4,4) # Sub-matrix dimensions
displs = (0, 4, 32, 36)

counts = (1, 1, 1, 1) 
starts = (0,0)

mynum = counts[rank]
glob = np.empty((8,8), dtype = 'f')
local = np.empty((4,4), dtype = 'f')

if rank == 0:  # Fill each quadrant with 0-3

    for row in range(0,4):
        for col in range(0,4):
            glob[row, col] = 0
    for row in range(0,4):
        for col in range(4,8):
            glob[row, col] = 1
    for row in range(4,8):
        for col in range(0,4):
            glob[row, col] = 2
    for row in range(4,8):
        for col in range(4,8):
            glob[row, col] = 3
    print glob

submatrixType = MPI.DOUBLE.Create_subarray(sizes, subsizes, starts, order =    MPI.ORDER_C)
submatrixType.Commit()

sendbuf = [glob, counts, displs, submatrixType]
recvbuf = [local, 16, MPI.DOUBLE]

comm.Scatterv(sendbuf, recvbuf, root = 0)
# or use
#comm.Scatterv(sendbuf, recvbuf, MPI.DOUBLE)

print rank, " " ,local
```

My results are as follows when running with 4 processes:

```
Proc 0: [[0. 0. 0. 0.] 
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
      File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    comm.Scatterv(sendbuf, local, root = 0)
comm.Scatterv(sendbuf, local, root = 0)
  File "Comm.pyx", line 454, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatterv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:67458)
  File "Comm.pyx", line 454, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatterv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:67458)
mpi4py.MPImpi4py.MPI.Exception: .Exception: MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    comm.Scatterv(sendbuf, local, root = 0)
  File "Comm.pyx", line 454, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatterv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:67458)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
```

Do i have the wrong idea about Create_subarray or what could else be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your 'displacements'.  You've correctly described a subarray type with 'sizes', 'subsizes', and 'starts', but when you displace this type, you've shifted the type description off the end of the actual 2d array.

Displacing other types is usually not a problem, but with subarray, you have this "original array" notion that is going to give issues.

I did a quick subsitution for VECTOR, but I still got a memory corruption.

Comment: I ended using C++ for my application instead. The mpi4py didn't really cut it in the end and i had problems solving over stepping of memory. Thank you for your input!